# Proving that the intersection of closed sets is closed

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I am having major trouble on this homework and need help!
Let $*$ be a binary operation on a set A.  Let B and C be subsets of A that are closed under $*$.

> a) Prove that $B \cap C$ is closed under $*$
>
> b) Give an example to show that $B \cup C$ need not in general be closed under $*$

Is this just some basic theorem of set intersections? I've been scanning my textbook and can't find a thing. Am I overthinking?

Answer (score 2):

If $x,\ y \in B \cap C$, then $x, \ y \in B$ and $x, \ y\in C$, both of which are closed under *. So what can you say about $x$ * $y$?

For b), consider $A=\Bbb Z$, the integers and *$=+$. Let $B= 3 \Bbb Z$ and $C = 2\Bbb Z$, that is multiples of $2$ and $3$ respectively. Each are closed under addition respectively, as $2x+2y=2(x+y)$ and similarly $3x+3y=3(x+y)$. However, $2+3 \not\in 2\Bbb Z$ or $3\Bbb Z$, so $2 \Bbb Z \cup 3 \Bbb Z$ isn't closed under addition.

Comment: I would say that x*y would be in B and C no? So then it would also be in B intersection C? Thus proving that it is closed?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it.

Comment: nice!  Thanks for the help man!

Comment: @user69839:  If this answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the 'tick'.

Comment: @DylanYott, can you please say, what are $3 \Bbb Z$ and $2 \Bbb Z$?

Comment: @Student, you mean triples like $\{x = (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in 3 \Bbb Z \mid x_i \in \Bbb Z, i = 1, 2, 3\}$?

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov No, I meant multiples of $3$, used the wrong word, I will edit it. (EDIT: I was to late to edit it, so I will remove the comment and write a new one under this one).

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov We denote by $3 \mathbb{Z}$ all multiples of $3$, so we find the set $3\mathbb{Z} = \{\ldots, -6,-3,0,3,6,\ldots \}$.

Comment: @Student, oh, then you must mean that it is the set of all multiples of 3, yes? But in $\Bbb Z$

Comment: @Student, thanks, I got it :) Sorry, didn't notice the last comment

Comment: @DylanYott, I suggest you edit your answer. Because $2 \Bbb Z \cap 3 \Bbb Z$ is actually the set of one element $\{0\}$. And which is closed under $+$. I think you wanted to write union instead of intersection.

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov So you mean that $6$ is not an element of $2\mathbb{Z}$ or $3 \mathbb{Z}$? ;) (we can show that $n\mathbb{Z} \cap m \mathbb{Z} = \text{gcd}(n,m)\mathbb{Z}$ and this is clearly not the trivial subgroup. I have edited the $\cap$, since it was a typo.

Comment: @Student, ahaha, I am stupid :D Thank you again. I am just at the beginning of math.
But what about changing intersection to union? Actually even if intersection is the set of all multiples of $6$, it is closed again, no? At least option a), which we have proved, says it.

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov the intersection of subgroups is again a subgroup. However, his point is that the union is not: $2 \in 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $3 \in 3\mathbb{Z}$. However, $2 + 3 = 5$ is not an element of $2 \mathbb{Z} \cup 3\mathbb{Z} = \{\ldots, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, \ldots \} \cup \{\ldots, -6,-3,0,3,6,\ldots \}$, showing that the union is not closed under the addition (so it is not a subgroup).